# Is data generated via a multivariate normal distribution consistent with OLS assumptions?

Tags: least-squares

Suppose I know 3 variables $A,B,Y$ have the following correlation matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho_{AB} & \rho_{AY}\\ 
\rho_{AB} & 1 & \rho_{BY}\\ 
\rho_{AY} & \rho_{BY} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Suppose I generate some fake data using a multivariate normal distribution such that

$$(A,B,Y) \sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\ 
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho_{AB} & \rho_{AY}\\ 
\rho_{AB} & 1 & \rho_{BY}\\ 
\rho_{AY} & \rho_{BY} & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Would this data set violate any of the OLS assumptions necessary to construct a linear model? 
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_A A_i + \beta_B B_i + \epsilon_i$$

In particular, would the spherical errors assumption hold, i.e.

$$Var(\epsilon|X) = \sigma^2 I$$

Or conditional mean 
$$E[\epsilon |X] = 0$$

where $X$ is the design matrix comprised of the columns of data $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You are looking at the model for $Y$ given $A,B$. What's the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) $(Y|A,B)$?

Comment: I assume then deriving that would help me solve this problem and I should do it and then reassess for myself how it would impact the OLS assumptions. Does that make sense or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I wasn't expecting you to derive it; I was assuming you were already familiar with it. But, certainly if you're able to derive it and haven't seen it before that may help you understand it. However, at the least you should be able to use the conditional distribution to answer your own questions. Note that $\epsilon$ is simply $Y-E[Y|A,B]$ (NB that expectation is linear in A, B, as you can see at the link), so computing its expectation and variance is not so difficult. Note, for example, that $\bar{\Sigma}$ is a constant.

Comment: Ok thanks very much. Also thanks very much generally for your contributions on CV.

Comment: If you are able to sort it out you may be able to post an answer.

Comment: I will. I am trying to contribute more to answering where I can to challenge myself to learn more.